# Shopify app proxy + Heroku + AWS bucket - Receiving CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am developing a Shopify app using Ruby On rails, Heroku and hosted the dynamic images in AWS S3 bucket. While I develop a front end page using Shopify proxy, Every thing works fine. But the images from AWS S3 have not loaded and in console, I am receiving the error message as below,

> Access to Image at
>   'tomrain.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/productoptions/left_side_previews/000/000/003/original/side-lft.png?1496235245'
>   from origin 'ram-tom.myshopify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'ram-tom.myshopify.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I am trying to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow from this specific domain, but could not find a clear solution. I am not sure whether it can be managed from shopify or through my coding.

Any suggestions or idea would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code where you're setting the header.

Comment: Hi, I used three different ways for setting header in ruby on rails,

1. In controller,
`response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

2. In Controller
`def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end`

3. In config/application.rb

`config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => "*"
}`